# How many manifolds are there?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I think there are three questions here, an answer to any would be interesting:

1. How many compact manifolds are there?
2. How many (not necessarily compact) manifolds are there?
3. How many compact/not-compact manifolds of dimension $n$ are there?

I know there exist uncountably many smooth structures on $\Bbb R^4$, so there are up to diffeomorphism uncountably many smooth manifolds. I also know there are only countably many compact $2$d manifolds.

Here I would view to manifolds as being the same if there is a homeomorphism between them, but I would restrict to smooth manifolds and not to topological manifolds. These definitions are basically arbitrary, so I don't really mind if you take a different view.

Comment: See [here](http://geometry.research.narkive.com/F9xaFKJb/how-many-compact-manifolds-are-there). The question is too broad, I think. See also  [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198098/are-there-only-countably-many-compact-topological-manifolds).

Comment: Interesting link, it leads me to understand that I should require the non-compact manifolds to be connected. At least if one wants to have a chance of getting countably many.

Comment: in the second link posted by Dietrich, the answer from "algori" tells you that there are uncountably many open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are not pairwise homeomorphic. so to sum things up: compact manifolds, countably many; non-compact manifolds: uncountably many

Comment: note that you can't get more manifolds up to homeo than the cardinality of the power set of the reals, since you can embed each manifold into some finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$. I guess you can ask if you get the cardinality of the continuum or of the power set of the continuum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There are countably many compact topological manifolds (up to homeomorphism). This is actually quite nontrivial, proven in

J. Cheeger and J. M. Kister, Counting topological manifolds, Topology, vol. 9, (1970) p. 149–151.

2. Continuum of topological manifolds (up to homeomorphism). This is so already for surfaces.
3. Same as (1) and (2).

Comment: I had forgotten to accept your answer, sorry. A remark: somebody told me that compact smooth manifolds always admit a triangulation, with this one can easily see that there can only be countably many homeomorphism classes of smooth manifolds.

Comment: @s.harp: Yes, this is a theorem due to Cairns. One also knows that each compact triangulated manifold supports only finitely many smooth structures, so there are only countably many diffeomorphism classes of smooth compact manifolds.